# Undefined property: App\Models\Invoice::$created_by

Tags: laravel-5

Invoice model

```
    protected $fillable = ['invoice_number', 'created_by', 'coupon_id', 'total_transaction', 'service_charge'];

    public function created_by()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by');
    }
```

User model

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'phone', 'user_status_id', 'email_activation_token', 'role_id'
    ];

    public function invoice()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Invoice', 'created_by');
    }
```

User has many Invoice, Invoice belongs to User

Here is my controller

```
$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->invoice_number = '#INV' . $latestInvoiceId + 1;
$invoice->created_by()->associate(Auth::user());
$invoice->total_transaction = $invoice_total;
$invoice->save();
```

But I get this

```
ErrorException in BelongsTo.php line 91:
Undefined property: App\Models\Invoice::$created_by
in BelongsTo.php line 91
```

Stack Trace

https://paste.laravel.io/1XQQp

Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change column to `created_by_id` and set relation too solved my problem.